# Trying to show a given figure is indeed a rhombus

Tags: vectors

[image]

In the following diagram, I want that $\vec{OB} + \vec{OA} = \vec{OA_1}$. In order to have this, I need $OAA_1B$ to be a rhombus. How can I show this?

Info: Points $A_1,B_1,C_1,D_1$ are symmetric around midpoints of sides of the quadrilateral about $O$

Comment: Do you mean parallelogram rather than rhombus? For it to be a rhombus, you require OA and OB to have equal lengths

Comment: you are right. how can we show it is a parallelogram indeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$, then $$\overrightarrow{OM}=\underline{b}+\frac 12(\underline{a}-\underline{b})=\frac 12(\underline{a}+\underline{b})$$

Therefore $$\overrightarrow{OA_1}=2\times\overrightarrow{OM}=\underline{a}+\underline{b}\Rightarrow\overrightarrow{AA_1}=\underline{b}=\overrightarrow{OB}$$

Hence it is a parallelogram